# Is there school today?

Tags: grammar

"There is no school today."

> Is today school?
>
> Is there school today?

How to make the sentence into a question to ask a kid is there school that day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question:

> How to make the sentence into a question to ask a kid ***is there
>   school that day?***

The answer is self-evident:

> Is there school today?